# IE 8 compatibility mode

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, compatibility

I have the following problem:

My css is the following:

```
.SPImage img
 {
    margin-top:-15px;
    float:left;
    white-space:normal;
    width:194px;
    height:149px;
 }
```

my HTML is the following:

```
<DIV id=SPImage class=SPImage>

<DIV style="POSITION: relative; WIDTH: 100%">
<IMG style="WIDTH: 165px; MARGIN-LEFT: 15px" title="test" alt="test" src="/resources/2710004.jpg">
</DIV>
</DIV>
```

I have the following setting in HTML head tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

my problem is that when I'm using IE 8, I have image raised up to 15px due to `margin-top:-15px;` when using IE 7 and IE8 in compatibility it appears just ok. I can't remove `margin-top:-15px;` because it will look ugly in IE 7.

[image]

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: use iedeveloper toolbar. change the margin and see the effect. changing it a little should work. else use inline style for test. if this doesn't work, you'll hav to use a separate css file to include in comments

Comment: @MLS, I used Ideveloper, unfortunately it changing a little doesn't work. all problem is margin-top:-15px;

Comment: If you have `IE=EmulateIE7` then it doesn't matter what it looks like in "IE8 mode". All IE8 users will see the site in "IE7 mode", in which it works.

Comment: Did you use a CSS reset at the beginning of your css file? this will solve alot of problems crossbrowser. This is a good css-reset: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: I assume you have a doctype, otherwise you'll be in quirks mode, which makes IE go crazy, no matter what compatibility mode you're in.

Comment: Also, I recommend avoiding compatibility mode if possible: it isn't a 100% accurate clone of a real IE7, plus it encourages bad practice and making sites that don't work in any other browser. So unless you absolutely *have* to use it, it's better to fix your code so it works properly in IE7 and IE8. This way, you'll also have a better chance of the same code working okay in other browsers too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When i do this:

CSS:

```
.SPImage img {
    margin-top:-15px;
    float:left;
    white-space:normal;
    width:194px;
    height:149px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<DIV id="SPImage" class="SPImage">
    <IMG style="WIDTH: 165px; MARGIN-LEFT: 15px" title="test" alt="test" src="img url">
</DIV>
```

In IE 7, IE 8, IE9, Chrome and FF it is looking the same?